# Select from multiple tables in MySQL join should be using JOIN not GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, select

**EDIT:**

With help from '@juergen d' I was finally able to create this query.

```
SELECT p.name as Product, c.name as Company, r.name as Reseller 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN companies c ON c.id = p.company_id 
INNER JOIN resellers_match rm ON c.id = rm.reseller_id 
INNER JOIN reseller r ON rm.reseller_id = r.id
ORDER BY p.name
```

**ORIGINAL:**

Title: Select from multiple tables in MySQL join? group by?

I have 4 tables:

```
1- resellers [id, name, etc..]
2- resellers_match [id, reseller_id, company_id]
3- companies [id, name, etc..]
4- products [id, name, company_id, etc..]
```

I need to select * from products where company_id matches company_id.reseller_match and reseller.reseller_match = x;

I not being able to find how I can do that. Thank you.

Comment: That is a normal join. Just go for it and post the query if you get stuck

Comment: @juergend is this correct?
SELECT p.name as Product, c.name as Company, r.name as Reseller
FROM products p, reseller r 
    INNER JOIN companies c ON c.id = p.company_id
    INNER JOIN resellers_match rm ON c.company_id  = rm.reseller_id 
ORDER BY p.name;

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.name as Product, c.name as Company, r.name as Reseller 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN companies c ON c.id = p.company_id 
INNER JOIN resellers_match rm ON c.id = rm.reseller_id 
INNER JOIN reseller r ON rm.reseller_id = r.id
ORDER BY p.name
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c.company_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: I corrected it. It is `c.id` instead of `c.company_id`. Come on. You could have found that out on your own.